# Why doesn't the UILabel show when the simulator is in Landscape Mode?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to make this UILabel show correctly in the landscape mode of the iPhone simulator. I think that I have already made fine constraints with AutoLayout mechanism.

### Here is my StackView constraints:

[image: StackView constraints]

### Here is my CountLabel constraints:

[image]

### When switching to the landscape mode:

[image]

### What I expect is:

[image]

Please help me fix this problem. 
Is there anything wrong with my constraints?

Comment: shouldn't your constraint to stackview be <= ?

Comment: @OmarChaabouni is correct try with his suggested way.

Comment: Do you have any constraints or intrinsic sizes to the subviews in your stack view? With the images you've shown, it looks like you're expecting the stack view to somehow switch from a `4 x 5` grid to a `4 x 3` grid? Stack view won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the constraint of countLabel.top and stackView.bottom.
Or you can change the constraint of countLabel.top and stackView.bottom to <=